# Why doesn't my basic program through Selenium and Java works?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I used the code below to login into *amazon* website and it works but somehow its not identifying the element for password.

```
driver.get("accounts@gmail.com");
WebElement signIn = driver.findElement(By.id("Email"));
signIn.sendKeys("XXX@gmail.com");
signIn.submit();
WebElement pwd = driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd"));
pwd.sendKeys("password");
pwd.submit();
```

Comment: The url is working i am able to enter the email id but when the page moves to password i am not to enter the password. My test is failing at the page where i have to enter the password.

Answer (score 2):

Within `driver.get()` line instead of your `EmailID` you need to pass the relevant *amazon url* as an example **`https://www.amazon.com/`**.

So instead of:

```
driver.get("accounts@gmail.com");
```

You would like to:

```
driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/");
```

Answer (score 0):

1. To run the code, place a valid URL in the statement `driver.get(<URL>)`. For Example: `driver.get("www.amazon.com)`. This will successfully open the Amazon site in whichever browser your driver is trying to open

2.You have mentioned in a comment as "code is failing for sending value to password field". I would suggest you to write an Xpath for it, if the id locator isn't working.

However, if you want the people to help you out more, please place the HTML code of your page and also error received, it will be easy to debug and also to provide accurate answer.